# Bootstrap tooltip changes position on its own

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, tooltip

im use bootstrap 4.3.1 version along with the vue.js version 2

my code

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7">
               <div
                   class="tooltip-icon"
                   @click="show = !show"
                   id="tooltip-button-1"
               ></div>
               <b-tooltip
                   :show.sync="show"
                   target="tooltip-button-1"
                   custom-class="tooltip-custom"
                   placement="bottom"
                   triggers="click"
               >
                   <div class="tooltip-text-title">
                        Тест
                   </div>
               </b-tooltip>
           </div>
       <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "Test",
    data() {
        return {
            show: false,
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

and in this case, if I change the style of the tooltip, I increase its max-width on 1000px or more (.tooltip-inner), and if its width is greater than that of the parent (col-md-7), it changes the placement to the left

it turns out that the tooltip cannot go beyond the column

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I did not see any issue in that. Tooltip is behaving correct as per the col `width` (`col-md-7`) provided.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    show: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.12.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.5.0/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.12.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
      <div class="col-md-7" style="background-color: yellow">
        <div @click="show = !show" id="tooltip-button-1">
          Click Me
        </div>
        <b-tooltip target="tooltip-button-1" triggers="click" placement="bottom">Тест</b-tooltip>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please see my next answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    show: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.12.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.5.0/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.12.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container" style="max-width: 1024px;">
    <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
      <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 55%; overflow-y: scroll">
        <div @click="show = !show" id="tooltip-button-1">
          Click Me
        </div>
        <b-tooltip target="tooltip-button-1" triggers="click" placement="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</b-tooltip>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: red; width: 45%;">
           <div style="height: 40px"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <style>
    .tooltip-inner {
        max-width: 300px!important
    }
    </style>
```

I found a more correct interpretation of my error

it appears if the block has scrolling

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).